# Getting heat rash from tefillin

Tags: tefilin, medicine, how-to

Summer is here, and it seems to have brought me some problems.

I seem to be getting heat rash from my *tfillin shel yad*. During, and for another half hour or so after davening, my arm gets all red and itchy where the tfillin are, and even between the straps.
I don't think this is an allergy, because it's very recent with the heat, but i suppose it's still possible.

Any ideas on how to prevent/reduce the rash, while still wearing the tfillin halachically?

Comment: Sure it's "[heat rash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miliaria)"? ...doesn't seem like something you get from tefillin

Comment: I can't make a positive medical identification, but it sure seems to be a heat-induced itchy rash.

Comment: Maybe try wearing someone else's tefillin first to see if it's just your pair?

Comment: If your tefillin are that hot, you should make sure that the parshiyot are okay....

Comment: Can you Daven someplace with better air conditioning?

Comment: You may want to consult a dermatologist about identifying the problem, and what he recommends. I've found that rubbing some moisturizer on your arm reduces the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I met someone who said his skin had a bad reaction from the tefilin. He told me he consulted with Rabbi Moshe Heinemann shlit'a, who observed that any material that's theoretically kosher to be used as tefilin housing is not a halachic barrier between the tefilin and the skin. Therefore Rabbi Heineimann told him to put a piece of soft doe skin [or parchment, I would assume] between the tefilin and his skin.